# Set of enumerator values in a class with EBean and Postgres

Tags: jpa, playframework, ebean

I'm using Play Framework 2.0.1 and the build in EBean to access my DB data.

I have an enumerator Temperature which holds values like: HOT, WARM, COLD, etc.

I have a class which is mapped to a database table. In this class I would like to be able to store a set of the Temeprature values, however, I don't know how to map it with EBean.

So far I have:

```
    Set<Temperature> temperature;

    @ElementCollection 
    @Column(name = "TEMPERATURES", nullable = false)
    public void setTemperature(Set<Temperature> temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }
```

However, when I run my app the evolution sript did not include creation of the TEMPERATURES column.

Any ideas how to do it correctly?